# How to Import Javafx8 in a bundle in OSGI

Tags: osgi, bundle, javafx-8

I'm working on an OSGI application with Felix. Now I want to use some JavaFx8 classes in a bundle but I have the following error :

```
Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javafx.geometry
```

How can I import JavaFx8 SDK packages in my bundle.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you want to write an OSGi based JAVAFX GUI or do you just want to use some utility classes such as the ones from the javafx.geometry package without starting a GUI window?

Comment: I need to create a complete GUI and I'll need an important number of imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the library to the felix classpath and append the necesary package(s) to the org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra option.
http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html
If you do so, the bundle no. 0 will export the required packages. I can provide more detailed instructions later my pc, right now i am on mobile.

Comment: the option org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra is in which file ? I'm using maven-pax-plugin to create the project and fire Felix.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have this config in karaf 3.0.2 here: ~/apache-karaf-3.0.2/etc/config.properties

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on an OSGI application with Felix. Now I want to use some
>   JavaFx8 classes in a bundle
>
> I need to create a complete GUI and I'll need an important number of
>   imports.

I've released some Early Access versions of [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DromblerFX), a new Rich Client Platform for JavaFX based on OSGi (Apache Felix) and Maven.

As an application framework it makes sure JavaFX and OSGi will get started properly and it provides the main window.

You can read more about Drombler FX here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/search/label/Drombler

There's a [Getting Started](http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted) page which explains how to create, build and run a Drombler FX sample application with a few simple steps.

Comment: I think I had to be more clear. Actually I'm working on an OSGI app which contains just one bundle that creates an JavaFX JFXPanel with animations. all the rest is Swing and allready created. I just need to make my bundle access to javafx packages from the JDK as it does for Swing packages for instance. I'm using maven-pax-plugin so I don't quite see how to do.

Answer (score 0):

After several researches, I finally fixed the problem by adding the packages I need in the pom.xml of the project :

```
<configuration><provision>
        <param>--platform=felix</param>
        <param>--noConsole</param>
        <param>--systemPackages=javafx.animation,javafx.application,javafx.collections,javafx.embed.swing,javafx.geometry,javafx.scene,javafx.scene.layout,javafx.scene.transform,javax.swing,javax.swing.border,org.osgi.framework</param>
      </provision></configuration>
```

or by adding the following properties to the same file ( pom of the project ):

```
<properties>
<org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra>javafx.animation,javafx.application,javafx.collections,javafx.embed.swing,javafx.geometry,javafx.scene,javafx.scene.layout,javafx.scene.transform,javax.swing,javax.swing.border,org.osgi.framework
</org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra>
<org.osgi.service.http.port>8080</org.osgi.service.http.port>
<org.osgi.service.http.port.secure>8443</org.osgi.service.http.port.secure>
```

For [More information](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.ops4j.general/8574) check the link.